# Force one NavigationLink to the detail view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui, master-detail

I have a master-(primary)-detail setup in my app, where most of the list items in the top-level NavigationView go to another list of submenu items, with .isDetailLink(false), and then those submenu items then navigate to the detail view. This is all working as intended.

I'm trying to also put in a NavigationLink in the top level list to got to my settings page, which I want to force into the detail view. There isn't a submenu for this link, so I tried to navigate to it directly and force .isDetailView(true). However, this causes the view to open in what would be the primary window above, but hidden at first. The detail window only has a back button, which then makes the intended view pop out from the menu column.

Is there a way to force only the settings menu item to open in the detail view, essentially skipping one navigation level?

Thanks!

Here's the simplified version of what I'm currently trying:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: SubMenu1()) {Text("MenuItem1")}
                    .isDetailLink(false)
                
                NavigationLink(destination: SubMenu2()) {Text("MenuItem2")}
                    .isDetailLink(false)
                
                NavigationLink(destination: SubMenu3()) {Text("MenuItem3")})
                    .isDetailLink(false)
                
                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsView()) {Text("Settings")}
                    .isDetailLink(true)
            }
        }

    }
}



struct SubMenu: View {
    var body: some View {
     
        List {
            ForEach(menuItems, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item)) {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE
I've taken some screenshots to illustrate the issue:

The top level navigation view:
[image: Top level Navigation View]

With one of the sub-menus selected, and .isDetailView(false). This is working properly:
[image: With one of the sub-menus selected, and .isDetailView(false). This is working properly]

Settings does not have a sub-menu like the others, so I want it to open directly on the right hand side. Instead, it opens like this, and is only revealed when the back button is pressed:
[image: Settings View]
[image]

Comment: Can you try "Context Menu" using SwiftUI, that will be very comfortable for showing submenu with actions

Comment: A context menu wouldn't be suitable a suitable UX choice here. The app is acting as a catalogue or index, so the top level list is categories, with the Submenu being all the items of that category, and the detail view being more detail about each item.

Comment: Yes, I understood your opinion about the context menu. But, I am afraid that I didn't understand your problem clearly. Can you provide some Sample Screenshots?

Comment: I have updated the post with screenshots, which should illustrate the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey, I have seen your screenshots. I Think you are using NavigationView 2 times there in Settings. Please remove any one of them, It should work fine!**